# using java function on jsp causes an error

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, server-side

i'm doing a school project and i could use some help with this code:
    i'm trying to invoke this method on a java page:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

package Test;
public class SendMail {

    public static void () {

        final String username = "";
        final String password = "";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("shov.rz@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("shov.rz@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function on a jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
    <%@page import="Test.SendMail" 
       SendMail.test(); %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

the java class is imported currectly but the eclipse refuses to run this program.
i must add that i'm using eclipse galileo with apache tomcat.
am i doing something wrong?

Comment: When you was "Eclipse refuses to run this program," what does that mean? What happens when you try to run it? How are you trying to run it? Do you get any sort of error message?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
charset=windows-1255
```

I suggest you use UTF-8 instead. It would be far more portable.

(There's no obvious sign that you even *are* calling the method from the page.)

By the way, currently you've got a method with the same name as your class - I would **strongly** discourage you from doing that. Aside from anything else, Java conventions are to use `camelCase` for method names.

Comment: i added the calling-the-function part that i've forgotten.

Comment: @user2445729: Does it still cause problems if you *don't* include that? (If so, then clearly the method is irrelevant.)

Comment: the code on my computer is a little different but this is the exception i get:
An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /trial.jsp
The method test() is undefined for the type SendMail
2:     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
3:     <%@page import="shoval.SendMail" %>
4:     <%
5:      shoval.SendMail.test();
6:     %>

Answer (score 1):

after you compile the code successfully, place it under the web-inf/classes/ folder.
place all the jar file you need to compile this class under the web-inf/lib folder.

within the jsp page you should have this

......
< %@ page import="test.SendMail" % >

<%
//call the function here

```
SendMail.send();
```

%>

.....

Comment: the eclipse refuses to compile the code. it throws an exception:
An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /trial.jsp
The method test() is undefined for the type SendMail
2:     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
3:     <%@page import="shoval.SendMail" %>
4:     <%
5:      Test.SendMail.test();
6:     %>

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to call a method called `test()`. Your class has a method called `send()` instead.

Also, since it's a static method, you don't need an instance of the class to call it. Simply call `SendMail.send();`.

Comment: yes, i changed the names and cancelled the obj object because this is a static method.